# Converting fetch_all array into single array in python

Tags: python, arrays

In python I have fetchall data from the database.

```
SENTENCE = "It is wonderful. I'am happy"
sent= (word_tokenize(SENTENCE))

cursor = conn.cursor()
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(sent))
cursor.execute("SELECT emotion_type FROM emotion WHERE key_word IN (%s)" % format_strings,tuple(sent))
results = cursor.fetchall()
for i in results:
        z= (i)
```

The output is

```
('happy',)
('happy',)
```

But I want to get this result as

```
['happy','happy']
```

If there is any possible way to get output as I want. Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the results will only be from a single column, then you can always do

```
results = [res[0] for res in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Thank you. this was what I exactly wanted.